# python: processing string from each row of loaded json

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-3.6

i have a json with tweet data which usually has a twitter handle at the start.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_json(filename, orient=columnName),columns=columnName)
```

I can load and index the tweet data using pandas, but I'm wondering how i can intelligently process each row to remove the handle if it is at the start of the tweet (ignore all other times it is used)

```
data['full_text']
```

example tweets:

```
@ABC hi there, how much for an apple
@ABC hi there, how much for an orange
@ABC hi there, how much @ABC for an pineapple
hi there @ABC, how much for an car
@ABC hi there, how much for an tree
```

would become:

```
hi there, how much for an apple
hi there, how much for an orange
hi there, how much @ABC for an pineapple
hi there @ABC, how much for an car
hi there, how much for an tree
```

There is the iterrows() command although from what I've read it is not advisable for modification, e.g. more for printing rows for example

===================

```
for datum in data['full_text']:
    print(datum)
    datum=re.sub("@ABC", "",datum,1)
    print(datum)
```

I also have the above, but isn't this bad practise? the examples i see in console seem fine, although I wouldn't be able to verify if i had a million records

Comment: You can just do `data = pd.read_json(...)` - not sure why you've got the extra `pd.DataFrame(...)` around it...

Comment: @JonClements, i originally did, but i found that the 'column' order changes after it is loaded in. e.g. i had "id_str" come first then "created_by" come second, but it was the other way round when i loaded into python and re-save the json or print to console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) - `^` means start of string and `\s+` one or more whitespaces:

```
data = pd.read_json(filename, orient=columnName) 
data['full_text'] = data['full_text'].replace('^@ABC\s+', '', regex=True)
print (data)
                                  full_text
0           hi there, how much for an apple
1          hi there, how much for an orange
2  hi there, how much @ABC for an pineapple
3        hi there @ABC, how much for an car
4            hi there, how much for an tree
```

Comment: i was going to ignore the whitespaces or apply some sort of trim function after, but two birds with one stone

Answer (score 2):

```
data['full_text'] = data['full_text'].str.replace(r'^(?:\@[^\s]+)\s*','')
```